# Network get very slow at noon everyday

Tags: windows, networking

My network gets very slow every workday starting at noon until around 1 PM. No updates are planed during that time. What could be the possible reasons why this is happening?

Comment: I blame solar flares. Also: chemtrails.

Comment: @EEAA What can I do? If I put tin foil on my server will it protect it from solar flares?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Employees could be doing personal activities during their lunch break such as watching YouTube videos.  If your router supports it you could do a packet capture of all network traffic, then load the capture up into Wireshark and do a conversation analysis to see which IPs are using the most traffic.  You can then use www.arin.net to see who owns those IPs to get a hint as to what services are eating up the network traffic.  You could also use nbtstat -a on the internal IP addresses to see which computer(s) on your LAN are responsible for using the traffic and then ask those employees if they know what's happening.  Depending on what sort of internet connection you have, it's also possible that you share a limited amount of bandwidth and other customers in the area are maxing it out during the lunch hour.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. Most website are block like games and Netflix but it could be YouTube since it's not blocked for learning purposes. I will try to find out if this has anything to do with my network. If other customers in the area are maxing the bandwidth, is there anything I can do to fix it?

Comment: You could contact your ISP.  I know in the case of cable internet, the ISP may need to do a node split if there are too many customers sharing.

Comment: I figured it out. Since I live on the East side of the country, when it's noon for me it's 9AM on the West side. This mean that this is around this time that a lot of users log in.

Answer (score 0):

See if you can get a hold of network analyzer or network monitoring tool. See what would be your peak hours and grab an average of users logging in and maybe bandwidth that is being used.

If you see a large number or a chunk of data, then you already know what your problem is

Comment: What do you mean by `you already know what your problem is`

Comment: Hi, kind of like the comment above. Could be the users and the bandwidth. Only way to tell is a network monitoring tool

Comment: What would be the solution?